# How to select the length of selected check box with name selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a list of check boxes and based on at least one selection , need to enable or disable a button.

The check box has name as they need to post back value to server.

Here is the code I tried:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
      console.log('cheeck box change');
    if ($("input[name='name1']:checked").length) {
        
        $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sub').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>

<input id='sub' type='button' value='Submit' disabled='disabled'>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara, This one sleek. Can you add this to answer.

Comment: that is not my work, its @chris-coyier , so I can't add it as my answer. :) I just found it on internet

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara, Thanks for honsety. You can still credit to the source in your answer. But this will really  help any one who comes to thispost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script might help you write it in a simple way.
Just select the checkboxes

`$("input[type='checkbox']")` and onclick `$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));`

full source code here

```js
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Do thing" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

It's a work of Chris Coyier, Thank you, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're making a small mistake in your selector `"input[name='name1']:checked"`, which should should instead be something like `"input[type='checkbox']:checked"`.

Currently' you're selecting input elements that have `name='name1'` which won't match any of your checkbox's because none of them have name attributes with value `"name1"`.

So, consider the following change:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
      console.log('cheeck box change');
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length) { // <-- update this line
        
        $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sub').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' class='check'> Value</p>

<input id='sub' type='button' value='Submit' disabled='disabled'>
```

If you need your form to work in this way, and want to select elements via a name selector, you could do something like this:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
      console.log('cheeck box change');
    if ($("input[name]:checked").length) { // <-- update this line
        
        $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sub').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='name-1' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='name-2' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='name-3' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='name-4' class='check'> Value</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='name-5' class='check'> Value</p>

<input id='sub' type='button' value='Submit' disabled='disabled'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            document.getElementById("sub").disabled = true;
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            document.getElementById("sub").disabled = false;
        }
    });
```

And check this link:[Try this link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-prop-method)